# Add user to Azure AD from another Azure AD via powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, office365, azure-active-directory

In the Azure [portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com) I can click *Add User* and select *User in another Windows Azure AD directory* to add a user from another directory to the current directory (As long as I have sufficient authorization in both directories).

I'd like to be able to do this via powershell, but it doesn't seem possible since you can only connect to a single directory.

Here's the scenario:
`admin@tenant1.onmicrosoft.com` is a global admin in both tenant1 and tenant2.  In the portal, I can see and manage both directories while logged as `admin@tenant1.onmicrosoft.com`.
But in powershell, if I do:

```
$cred = Get-Credential -UserName admin@tenant1.onmicrosoft.com
Connect-MsolService -Credential $cred
```

I can only see and manage the tenant1 directory.  So I tried this:

```
$cred = Get-Credential -UserName admin@tenant1.onmicrosoft.com
Connect-MsolService -Credential $cred
$user = Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName user@myfederateddomain.com

$cred2 = Get-Credential -UserName admin@tenant2.onmicrosoft.com
Connect-MsolService -Credential $cred2
$user | New-MsolUser
```

But this failed:

```
New-MsolUser : Unable to create this user because the user principal name provided is not on a verified domain.
At line:1 char:9
+ $user | New-MsolUser
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [New-MsolUser], MicrosoftOnlineException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.PropertyDomainValidationException,Microsoft.Online.Administ 
   ration.Automation.NewUser
```

I'm guessing this just isn't possible, but maybe someone can point out something I missed?

Comment: As of today, I've tried to do this via portal.azure.com - it works there, but the same operation from PowerShell - doesn't work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, as you had guessed, this functionality is not currently available through Azure AD PowerShell.  It is something that we'd like to add in the future, but I don't have an exact timeframe for this yet.

UPDATE 4/14/2018:  Sorry - was not monitoring this.  There is now a way to invite a user from another tenant to the current tenant using Microsoft Graph.  Please see https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/invitation.  It still doesn't look like there's any Azure AD PowerShell for this.

Comment: Does anyone know if there is an update to this, can this scenario be done now? or is there another way to do it?

Comment: Still doesn't work today via PS, so I guess no update yet.

Comment: See updated answer with an option for you (but still no PowerShell)